# How to access request body in nextjs 13.2 route handler

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, next.js13

I was trying to send a post request to my api. However trying to access the request body in the route handler causes the error below:

**Code:**

```js
export async function POST(request: Request) {
  const postBody: postProps = JSON.parse(request.body) //  Error here on request.body
  ...
}
```

**Error:**
Argument of type 'ReadableStream' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You need to call [`json()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/json) on the Request object.

```js
export async function POST(request: Request) {
  const res = await request.json() // res now contains body
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. So does request automatically contain body now in next 13.2 since i was used to req.body before?

Comment: What happens if you aren't receiving `application/json`? For me it errors out on Json parse

Comment: One question: if your type was not ````Request```` but ````NextApiRequest````, how would you then extract the body ? Thanks

Comment: @BlackLabrador `NextApiRequest` should only be used for the `/pages` directory. This question is for the `/app` directory. In that case, however, you'll use `JSON.parse(request.body)`, as shown in the question.

Comment: @AndrewK did you found an answer how to handle a case where you're not receiving an `application/json` body. For me it also errors out.

Comment: I have a serious question, Why they don't write such things in the documentation? I mean how do you expect people to work on POST request without accessing request.body?

Answer (score 6):

I was having issues Verifying the webhook from Clerk in Next.js using App Router.

The following worked for me.

```js
import { Webhook } from "svix";

export async function POST(req: NextRequest) {
  const svix_id = req.headers.get("svix-id") ?? '';
  const svix_timestamp = req.headers.get("svix-timestamp") ?? '';
  const svix_signature = req.headers.get("svix-signature") ?? '';
  
  const body = await req.text(); // This get's the raw body as a string
  
  const sivx =  new Webhook("your_secret_key_here")

  const payload = sivx.verify(body, {
    "svix-id": svix_id,
    "svix-timestamp": svix_timestamp,
    "svix-signature": svix_signature,

  });

  // The payload is the json.
  console.log(payload);

  // The rest of your code

  return NextResponse.json(null, { status: 200 })

}
```

For reference:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/text

Answer (score 3):

I was having trouble getting a Stripe webhook to work using App Router. The following worked for me (using Kyle's method of getting the raw body).

```
import Stripe from 'stripe';

const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY!, {
  apiVersion: '2023-08-16',
});

import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';

const WEBHOOK_SECRET = process.env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET;

export async function POST(req: NextRequest) {
  const rawBody = await req.text(); // gets the raw body from the request
  const sig = req.headers.get('stripe-signature');

  let event;
  let result = 'Webhook called.';

  try {
    event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(rawBody, sig!, WEBHOOK_SECRET!);
  } catch (err: any) {
    console.error(err);
    return NextResponse.json({ error: err.message }, { status: 400 });
  }

  // Handle the event
  switch (event.type) {
    case 'payment_intent.created':
      console.log('Payment Intent Created.');
      break;
    case 'payment_intent.payment_failed':
      console.log('Payment Failed.');
      break;
    case 'payment_intent.processing':
      console.log('Payment processing...');
      break;
    case 'payment_intent.succeeded':
      const paymentIntent = event.data.object;
      console.log('paymentIntent: ', paymentIntent);
      console.log(`Payment Succeeded`);
      break;
    // ... handle other event types
    default:
      console.warn(`Unhandled event type ${event.type}`);
  }
  return NextResponse.json({ received: true, status: result });
}
```

Also, you cannot call both req.json() and req.text(). You will get a body consumed error.

Comment: This one works.  use request.text() to get the correct body, I used it to verify Slack request.

Answer (score 1):

After battling with this issue for an hour, I had to comment `output` prop in `next.config.js` to get request.json() to deliver the request's body.

```
const nextConfig = {
    // "output": "export",
    "distDir": "build",
    experimental: {
        serverActions: true
    }
}
```

I'm still trying to understand the connection. Shouldn't I be able to build my client components to a dir?